# Transpose issues in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am having issues while transposing the data into a certain format.

I am trying to get the data into this format

[image: Fomat]

Below is the actual data which I am working against. There are multiple titles and dates.

[image: Excel data]

I am not sure if the transpose function would work as I tried that (result in the above cap) and failed.

Any help in this regard is useful. Do I need to use any macro or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating a pivot table based on your table of data (the left-most table on the second screenshot above).

To create a pivot table (no VBA required), click into the table of data and click Insert PivotTable and follow the wizard. Set the Title as the Row Field, Date as the Column Field and Count as the summary field.

This should result in exactly the layout you're after.

Comment: Aah crap...I should have looked more. Thanks for the tip...gracias :)